# Display tags next to date on Wordpress post list

Tags: wordpress

How do you display a Tag next to the date of a post in Wordpress? You can add tags to a post, but how do you display them next to the post?

I have the following code that pulls all posts in the Media Coverage category:

```
<div class="press_item">
                <?php $posts = get_posts('category_name=media-coverage&numberposts=300'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <p>Date posted: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p><hr>
                <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop:

```
<?php the_tags( $before, $sep, $after ); ?>
```

If you are outside the loop:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually figured this out a couple minutes after I posted.
<?php $before = "Publication: "; the_tags( $before, $sep, $after ); ?>